# WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on my app for Android 13+

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions

I'm new to mobile apps and exploring this world using Android Jetpack Compose. I want to create an application that can open a sqlite database that I downloaded and I want this application, even though it is not the owner of that database, to open it and be able to perform all the common manipulations and after using it, I can delete the file from the Downloads folder. I would like help with this, and especially in the permissions part as I use Android 13 and the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions no longer work for these new versions of Android. Can someone help me?.

I tried using the READ_MEDIA_... triad but they didn't give me the access I expected. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your question is well-explained in the Google Developer [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files).

For details, you can use `rememberPermissionsState` to request the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, if the result is false, guide the user to enable the permission that your app requires.

Comment: Thank you very much Ethan Wu. It worked for me